# Почему плагин mmenu работает некорректно?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, вёрстка, веб-интерфейс

Почему плагин [mmenu](https://mmenujs.com/) работает некорректно на мобильных диапазонах, например, 375px, если в HTML не указать `user-scalable=no, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0` ?

То есть, при такой записи плагин работает нормально:

```
<meta name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
```

А при такой записи возникают баги на маленьких мобильных диапазонах:

```
<meta name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Существует ли способ это исправить, чтобы плагин работал нормально без указания `user-scalable=no, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0` ?

Баг с меню начинается на всех диапазонах, которые ниже 550px, если не указать в HTML `user-scalable=no, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0`

Баг можно воспроизвести как на мобильном телефоне, так на десктопном браузере включив в инструментах разработчика мобильный режим.

Он заключается в том, что когда ширина окна браузера становится все меньше и меньше чем 550px, то обертка `.mm-menu_offcanvas`, в которой находится меню, не изменяет свою ширину, она всегда равна 440px (как указано в свойстве `max-width`, которое задает плагин). Получается из-за этого перестает быть видимой правая часть меню.

Для класса `.mm-menu_offcanvas` плагин задает вот такие свойства:

```
.mm-menu_offcanvas {
    width: 80%;
    min-width: 240px;
    max-width: 440px;
}
```

Но у меня уже получилось решить проблему. Вместо процентов, как указал плагин, задал единицу vw:

```
.mm-menu_offcanvas {
    width: 80vw;
}
```

После этого все стало отображаться нормально.

Answer (score 1):

Я использовал этот плагин неоднократно и ни когда не писал user-scalable вообще, если мне память не изменяет.
Также только что попробовал и не увидел ничего неожиданного.
Предполагаю, что проблема в чём то другом. Что есть не корректно, уточните, Сергей ?

Comment: Дополнил вопрос, описал более подробнее. У меня уже получилось исправить этот баг.

Answer (score 1):

Получилось решить проблему. Вместо процентов, как указал плагин, задал единицу vw:

```
.mm-menu_offcanvas {
    width: 80vw;
}
```

После этого все стало отображаться нормально.